# How to save QtreeView or QDialog state

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I made a File Tree with a check box. The program works well, but the status of the check box does not remain after the program is turned off. I want to keep the check box status even if I turn off the program and turn it on. No matter how many times i searched, I couldn't get the answer. Please help.
Thanks

.ui file :

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>902</width>
    <height>367</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTreeView" name="treeView">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>861</width>
     <height>321</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

My code :

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

form_window = uic.loadUiType("test.ui")[0]


class window(QDialog, form_window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.get_discs()


    def get_discs(self):
        self.treeView.model = CheckableFileSystemModel()
        self.treeView.model.setRootPath("")
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeView.model)


class CheckableFileSystemModel(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel):
    checkStateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.checkStates = {}

        self.rowsInserted.connect(self.checkAdded)

        self.rowsRemoved.connect(self.checkParent)
        self.rowsAboutToBeRemoved.connect(self.checkRemoved)



    def checkState(self, index):
        # checkStates={}로 리턴
        return self.checkStates.get(self.filePath(index), QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    def setCheckState(self, index, state, emitStateChange=True):
        path = self.filePath(index)
        if self.checkStates.get(path) == state:
            return
        self.checkStates[path] = state
        if emitStateChange:
            self.checkStateChanged.emit(path, bool(state))



    def checkAdded(self, parent, first, last):
        # if a file/directory is added, ensure it follows the parent state as long
        # as the parent is already tracked; note that this happens also when
        # expanding a directory that has not been previously loaded
        if not parent.isValid():
            return
        if self.filePath(parent) in self.checkStates:
            state = self.checkState(parent)
            for row in range(first, last + 1):
                index = self.index(row, 0, parent)
                path = self.filePath(index)
                if path not in self.checkStates:
                    self.checkStates[path] = state
        self.checkParent(parent)


    def checkRemoved(self, parent, first, last):
        # remove items from the internal dictionary when a file is deleted;
        # note that this *has* to happen *before* the model actually updates,
        # that's the reason this function is connected to rowsAboutToBeRemoved
        for row in range(first, last + 1):
            path = self.filePath(self.index(row, 0, parent))
            if path in self.checkStates:
                self.checkStates.pop(path)


    def checkParent(self, parent):
        # verify the state of the parent according to the children states
        if not parent.isValid():
            return
        childStates = [self.checkState(self.index(r, 0, parent)) for r in range(self.rowCount(parent))]
        newState = QtCore.Qt.Checked if all(childStates) else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        oldState = self.checkState(parent)
        if newState != oldState:
            self.setCheckState(parent, newState)
            self.dataChanged.emit(parent, parent)
        self.checkParent(parent.parent())

    # ??
    def flags(self, index):
        return super().flags(index) | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0:
            return self.checkState(index)
        return super().data(index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role, checkParent=True, emitStateChange=True):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0:
            self.setCheckState(index, value, emitStateChange)
            for row in range(self.rowCount(index)):
                # set the data for the children, but do not emit the state change,
                # and don't check the parent state (to avoid recursion)
                self.setData(index.child(row, 0), value, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole,
                             checkParent=False, emitStateChange=False)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            if checkParent:
                self.checkParent(index.parent())
            return True

        return super().setData(index, value, role)


    def closeEvent(self, event):

        settings = QSettings("MyCompany", "MyApp")
        # settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue("windowState", saveState())
        QMainWindow.closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window = window()
    Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Store the state of the checkbox in a file and read the file when you open the app again ?

Comment: Use [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html). Some widgets have `saveState`/`restoreState` methods that may be useful: [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#saveState), [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#saveState), [QHeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#saveState) & [QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#saveState). For everything else, you must write your own code to save/restore the state via the settings.

Comment: @rochard4u 
That's my goal. How can you make It happen?